# Prove that $((p\lor q)\land(p\lor(\lnot q)))\rightarrow p$ is a tautology

Tags: logic, proof-writing, propositional-calculus

Prove that **$((p\lor q)\land(p\lor(\lnot q)))\rightarrow p$**

Please could someone give me some feed back on this proof? Does it look correct?

= $\lnot ((p\lor q)\land(p\lor(\lnot q)))\lor p$

= $ (\lnot(p\lor q) \lor \lnot(p\lor(\lnot q)))\lor p$

= $((\lnot p\land \lnot q)\lor(\lnot p\land \lnot(\lnot q)))\lor p$

= $((\lnot p\land \lnot q)\lor(\lnot p\land q))\lor p$

= $(\lnot p(\lnot q \lor q)))\lor p$ <----- Is this step correct?

= $(\lnot p(T))\lor p$ $\equiv true $

Thanks a million

Comment: @amWhy has already pointed out the actual error, but I’ll note in addition that the fourth line duplicates the third.

Comment: Unless you're required to stick with a particular proof formalism, a plain truth table proof might be shorter and simpler.

Comment: (Though not shorter and simpler than amWhy's answer)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The step in question should be, using the distributive law: 
$$((\lnot p\land \lnot q)\lor(\lnot p\land q))\lor p$$
$$\equiv (\lnot p \land (\lnot q \lor q)) \lor p)$$

$$\equiv (\lnot p \land T) \lor p$$
$$\equiv \lnot p \lor p \equiv T$$

Comment: You're welcome: everything else looks good; just be sure to include your "justifications" for each step (DeMorgan's Law, etc.) in your final proof.

Comment: Will do thanks..